# Swapping position of letters

Tags: python

I am trying to swap position values.

`a` should be assigned with `e` and vice versa

`b` should be assigned with `g` and vice versa

Is there any simple way to do it?

**My code :**

```
str1="abcdefg"
clst=list(str1)
index_lst1=[]
index_lst2=[]
final_lst=[]

for i in range (len(clst)):
    if clst[i] == 'a' or clst[i] == 'b':
        index_lst1.append(i)
    elif clst[i] == 'e' or clst[i] == 'g':
        index_lst2.append(i)
    else:
        pass

final_lst.extend(index_lst1)
final_lst.extend(index_lst2)

for i in range(len(clst)):
    x=clst[0]
    y=clst[1]
    
    if i == 0:
        b=clst[4]
        clst[0]=b
        clst[4]=x
    elif i == 1 :
        c=clst[6]
        clst[1]=c
        clst[6]=y

print(clst)
```

**Expected Output :**

```
egcdafb
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just do this:

```
str1.translate(str.maketrans("abeg", "egab"))
```

That translates all a <-> e and all b <-> g.

Example:

```
>>> "abcdefg".translate(str.maketrans("abeg", "egab"))
'egcdafb'
```

Note that `maketrans` is a static method of the `str` class, which is why it's usually called as `str.maketrans()`, though it could be called from your `str1` string as `str1.maketrans()` as well. It's usually done the first way.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str1="abcdefg"
>>> swap = {
...     'a': 'e',
...     'b': 'g',
...     'e': 'a',
...     'g': 'b',
... }
>>> ''.join(swap.get(c, c) for c in str1)
'egcdafb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"".join([{"a":"e","e":"a","b":"g","g":"b"}.get(i, i) for i in "abcdefg"])
```

If you want to use a `for` loop with `if/elif` block, you can do:

```
str1="abcdefg"
output = ""
for c in str1:
    if c == "a":
        output += "e"
    elif c == "b":
        output += "g"
    elif c == "e":
        output += "a"
    elif c == "g":
        output += "b"
    else:
        output += c
```